# macOS Sonoma and the new Observable macro

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have one issue with the new Observable macro on Swift 5.9 on macOS Sonoma. Most of the old `@StateObject` and `@ObservableObject` are converted to the new `@Observable` macro. But I am struggling with converting one `@ObservableObject`. The not yet converted object works as expected, it automatically reports progress for a progress bar as it should. After converting to the new `@Observable` macro it does not report updates to the view. For all other converted objects it works as expected, but not the last one. Every time the model updates by `func setcurrentprogress` the "old" model communicates the changes to the view for update..

"Old" code which is working:

```
final class ProgressDetails: ObservableObject, ProgressDetailsProtocol {
    // Value for storing progress for current task in work
    private var currenttaskprogress: Double?
    private var estimatedlist: [RemoteinfonumbersOnetask]?

    ...

    func setcurrentprogress(_ num: Double) {
        currenttaskprogress = num
        objectWillChange.send()
    }

    ....
}
```

and the new code which is not working:

```
@Observable
final class ProgressDetails: ProgressDetailsProtocol {
    // Value for storing progress for current task in work
    var currenttaskprogress: Double?
    var estimatedlist: [RemoteinfonumbersOnetask]?

    ....

    func setcurrentprogress(_ num: Double) {
        currenttaskprogress = num
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce, perhaps the issue is with your view code.

Comment: Note that wherever you use `model.setcurrentprogress(num)` in your code, you could just use `model.currenttaskprogress = num`.
 If it is passed to a sub view, then you can also use `@Bindable var ...`. It would be best to show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The challenge to produce a minimal code is because the updates are caught one place in code by Combine (a publisher). The updates are then again caught by the model by a completion handler and the StateObject is responsible for publishing the changes. I could as you say just update the property direct and make it a `@Published var`, but the `objectWillChange.send()` on the ObservableObject does the same - it will publish a change. I have adapted about ten objects to the new macro and it works perfect. But the last one does not... And I cannot understand why...

Comment: In the [Discover Observation in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10149/), at time index 8:44, Apple mentions that there is one case where you have to manually indicate mutation, but it applies to a computed property (which is not what your example shows).  Nevertheless you might add a call to `withMutation` around `currenttaskprogress = num` and see if that causes the observation to fire.

Comment: Great and thx, I will try out the `withMutation` around the property. And thx for the link to video:-) Looking at it now...